# Is there an automated way for me to setup a 'default baseline' for my Rails Apps at the start of development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For instance, I know that when I start a new project there are certain gems I am going to want installed and setup.

- My User model, controller with all CRUD actions created
- My Assignment and Roles model - to set the stage for Authorization
- Devise installed and configured according to some preset settings
- Declarative Authorization setup and some set roles in place
- The routes file adjusted to accomodate all of the above
- My Environment files setup accordingly

Those are the main things that I find myself doing over and over again for every project.

I know that there are some tools for rolling out deployments of production servers (Capistrano and Chef I believe are two) according to specific configurations.

But those seem like overkill for my needs.

Is there something out there for what I want to do?

Of course I want the flexibility to be able to add any gem/engine with the appropriate configuration settings.

Comment: You can create your own generator. You have to weigh the time it takes to build the generator with the time you'll save using it, though.

Comment: I figured it's something I would have to create...I would do it over time. If no one else has some other solution, then it's something I will look into as a side project at some point. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah that's what generators are for really. Of course, you don't have to do an app generator, you could do just a model or a `devise:setup` generator that creates your user controller, model, adds devise, etc.

Comment: Interesting...will definitely look into it. If someone else has created something like this before, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is a special type of generator called an "application template." They are described in the [Rails guide on generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#application-templates). They let you do all sorts of things like adding gems to the Gemfile, copying files, running shell scripts, Rake tasks, etc.

If you'd like an example, I made one recently that sets things up the way I like: [railsapp](https://github.com/jimmycuadra/railsapp)

Answer (score 1):

Create an application template in git. Create a new Rails app. Then do all the step you noted

- create a User model, controller and views
- create your Assignment and Role models
- install and configure Devise
- install and setup DeclarativeAuth
- set up the routes
- set your environment

Check the whole thing into git, call it starter_app or something.

Then whenever you start a new project, fork the starter_app. If you do anything interesting the new project, pull them back into the starter_app.